# How Can I Set UISearchBar to Black Translucent Via Code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisearchbar

I know how to do this using IB, but how can I do this with just code?  OR do I manually have to do the RGB?

I have:

```
UISearchBar * searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this via two properties in UISearchBar;

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor
@property(nonatomic, assign, getter=isTranslucent) BOOL translucent
```

Set the `tintColor` to black, and set `translucent` to YES.

Check the reference for more info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this does the trick!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the barStyle property and translucent properties together:

```
UISearchBar * searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
searchBar.translucent = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just do the following:

`searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;`

Kool have fun :)